# How to develop in production and development mode of Flask website

Tags: python, flask

This is not a pure technical issue but more methodologic question.
I've seen Q&A regarding configuration for DEBUG and PRODUCTION ENVs but my question is concerning other issue.

When I started working on the project on my local machine I edited the hosts file to redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (I used the same URL for my live website) to 127.0.0.1 as I used to and it's working great.

Now when [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is live, I wanted to know what is the right configuration for keep developing the website?

The only idea I came up with is to use [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) (So I won't lose actual access to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) in my hosts file and on the code to use IF DEBUG to redirect traffic to example.org instead of example.com but I feel there are better options.

I also would love some tips about the right way of working with git to post local updates to the live server.

Comment: Please don't use existing domain names. Use special domains like example.com, example.net, example.org. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com . I replaced existing names with the examples.

Comment: Also I'm sure Flask is irrelevant here. My advice is to remove it from the tittle and the tags.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to access the website I'm running locally I just use http://127.0.0.1:5000 in my browser to access it.

If you've hardwired the domain "www.example.com" into your flask logic somewhere, i.e. when passing a redirect link to an OAuth service I would consider removing that hardcoded logic. Instead use an environment variable which you set differently on production/dev or else access to the current domain of a request with `request.url_root` or `request.headers['Host']`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Flask's [SERVER_NAME](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#SERVER_NAME) and [PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME) builtin configuration values.

```
class Config(object):

    # blah blah

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):    

    SERVER_NAME = "example.local"
    PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'http'


class ProductionConfig(Config):

    SERVER_NAME = "example.com"
    PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'https'
```

On your development machine map `example.local` to `127.0.0.1` .

Comment: so while testing on local i wouldn't use my real domain name in any way ?

Comment: @user2396640 Exactly. I normally use the project name converted to a suitable domain name e.g. `project1.local`, `project2.local`. Also, I run each project on a separate port.